# How does this infinite product work?

Tags: infinite-product, wolfram-alpha

${\displaystyle \prod_{n=1}^{\infty} ({ \frac n {n+1}}) ^{(-1)^n}}$

Typed this infinite product into Wolfram Alpha and I got an approximate result of 1.5708. I wonder if anyone studied this infinite product because I couldn't find anything about it on the web and thought that it was quite interesting. I'd be pleased if anyone can inform me about this infinite product.

Comment: That result seems reminiscent of $\pi/2$.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wallis_product

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can combine terms of the form $2n$ and $2n+1$. So, the product becomes $$\prod_{n=1}^\infty \bigg(\frac{2n}{2n-1}\bigg)\bigg(\frac{2n}{2n+1}\bigg)$$Which equals$$\prod_{n=1}^\infty \frac{4n^2}{4n^2-1}=\prod_{n=1}^\infty 1+\frac1{4n^2-1}$$This can be written as $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac1{2n+1}\cdot\frac{2^{4n}(n!)^4}{(2n)!^2}$$Which, by Stirling's approximation becomes $\frac\pi2$.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation!

Comment: Just a small comment on the language: you are combining two factors, not terms! A sum is made up of terms and a product is made up of factors.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy I believe that both are valid in the case of infinite products, but correct me if I'm wrong